# Replace empty space wherever Regex matches in a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have been trying to solve this problem. I have a string which has a pattern. Eg.

```
CW1234 has been despatched to CW334545
```

i.e the String can have patterns starting with `CW` followed by any number of intergers (at max `16`).

I want to replace all these patters with an empty character. So that the string will look like

```
has been despatched to
```

I have tried the following but it replaces only the first digit followed by the CW. I'm pretty new to java. Any insights would be of great help.

```
if(Pattern.matches(".*[C][W][0-9].*", str1)) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".*[C][W][0-9].*").matcher(str1);

    while(m.find()) {
        str1 = str1.replaceAll("[C][W][0-9]", "");
    }    
}

System.out.println(str1);
```

Comment: What if there are 17 digits? should only the first 16 be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're needlessly constructing the pattern and matching the string several times.

```
str1 = str1.replaceAll("CW\\d+", "");
```

This is sufficient. All other code is redundant.

You can also opt to do the replace by hand if performance is a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the simplest route.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have `{n,m}` quantifier on your digits, to enforce maximum digits. Also, for replacement purpose, you don't need to check beforehand whether the pattern is there or not. `replaceAll` will replace only if there is matching pattern, else will leave the string as it is.

So, remove all those `Pattern` and `Matcher` part, and change your regex to:

```
str1 = str1.replaceAll("CW\\d{0,16}", "");
```

If you want at least 1 digit, then make it `{1,16}`. No need to put `C` and `W` in different character classes. A character class with single character is as good as that character itself (given that it's not a special character). Also, you can use `\\d` instead of `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `replaceAll` is missing a `+`:

```
str1 = str1.replaceAll("[C][W][0-9]+", "");
```

The `+` will make the regex match any number of digits directly following `CW`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Klas. It worked. I'm learning new things in regex. Many thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You don't need to put `[]` around letters.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is wrong. Try with:

```
 String str1 = CW1234;
 str1 = str1.replaceAll("\\bCW\\d{0,16}\\b","");
```

if the "CW12134" is a single token in a string or with

```
 String str1 = CW1234;
 str1 = str1.replaceAll("^CW\\d{0,16}$","");
```

if the "CW1234" is a full string.

Answer (score 1):

`String.replaceAll("CW[0-9\\s]*", "")` does what you need, and it also removes the space at the end of the number.

On another note, the whole point of Pattern.compile() is that you need to compile the required expression once in the application, and then use the matcher to find occurences. So I think your usage is inappropriate (rather than incorrect).
`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("CD[0-9\\s]*");`occurs only once in the code and then reuse it as
`Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringToMatch);`